# How to setup Mailboxer (Gem) Views for Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, messaging, inbox, mailboxer

I'm looking for help setting up my views for the inbox, etc for Mailboxer.
Does anybody have any hints or can you give me a basic layout of what I should be doing?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Mailboxer provides [GUI examples on a real application](https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer/wiki/GUI-Example-on-a-real-application). There you will find examples of how to organize controllers and views.

Also, there is a [demo application](https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer#do-you-want-to-test-mailboxer) for Rails 4. Although views are specific to every application, it will give you a good starting point.

There is also a fairly recent tutorial on how to customize Mailboxer ruby gem [here](http://jamestansley.com/2014/02/22/customizing-the-mailboxer-ruby-gem-2/), and it covers setting up views.